# api gateway reverse proxy s3 exposing binary files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

we've got a bunch of files in s3 that we want to expose *to a web browser* - and are having problems.

Essentially we've setup the api gateway to reverse proxy to S3 - and if we use curl or wget to get the url - it sends the correct "Accept" header, everything is fine and dandy, and works perfectly.

However, if we go through a browser - which is the actual business need, then obviously we can't control what headers it sends.... and the file comes back corrupted.  If we look at what comes back in the response headers we get something like:

```
Content-Length: 62020
x-amzn-Repmapped-Content-Length: 46513
```

now, obviously 46513 is the correct size of the file, but the 62020 bytes that come back is some sort encoded garbage that doesn't unzip or display or otherwise... work.

Binary media types has only one item in it * / * - but as that seems to rely on the accept header, it still does nothing.

Is there any way to setup the rest service to "**just keep your grubby mitts off my file**" - ie pass through whatever you get, both content-type and datastream are passed through unmolested.

Comment: Could be base64 encoded. Did you check?

Comment: yes - I'm sure it's base64 encoded.  That would be the problem - how do I prvent that happening?

Comment: You haven't provided any information regarding your APi gateway setup, integration with s3. Its difficult to speculate.